# Model is null in partial view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'm trying to add a partial view inside a layout page.

Model

```
public class SummaryPanelModel
    {
        public int TotalDesignDocs { get; set; }
        public int TotalVendorDocs { get; set; }
        public int TotalBusinessDocs { get; set; }
        public int TotalManagementDocs { get; set; }
    }
```

SummaryPanel_Partial Partial View Controller:

```
 public ActionResult SummaryPanel_Partial()
        {
            rep = new SummaryRepository();
            SummaryPanelModel model = new SummaryPanelModel();
            model = rep.ReadsummaryPanel();//read from database
            return View(model);
        }
```

Layout Page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
@{
    Layout = null;
}

 @Html.Partial("SummaryPanel_Partial")
```

SummaryPanel_Partial Partial View:

```
@model Doc.Web.Models.SummaryPanel.SummaryPanelModel

<div id="pnlBar">
    @Html.Label(Model.TotalDesignDocs.ToString())
<div/>
```

despite the fact that I have passed the model in controller action, the model is always null in the partial view.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
@Html.Partial("SummaryPanel_Partial")
```

Calling a partial in this way **will not call the controller+action**. Instead, it simply finds the view `SummaryPanel_Partial` and renders it. Since you provide no model at this point, the model is null.

Instead, call `Html.Action`, which will call the controller+action.

```
@Html.Action("SummaryPanel_Partial", "Controller")
```

And change your action:

```
public ActionResult SummaryPanel_Partial()
{
    // ...
    return PartialView(model);
}
```

Comment: It also helped when I pointed `Ajax.BeginForm` to the correct action name. :)

Answer (score 1):

try using `PartialViewResult`

```
   public PartialViewResult SummaryPanel_Partial()
    {
       rep = new SummaryRepository();
        SummaryPanelModel model = new SummaryPanelModel();
        model = rep.ReadsummaryPanel();//read from database
        return PartialView(model);
    }
```

Comment: Isn't a `PartialViewResult` a type of `ActionResult`?  Shouldn't have to change the method signature.